# function to replace values in a table

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function from which the values in the table below can be extracted.
Now I want to write a function that multiplies the values entered in each input in a row and writes the result instead of the corresponding row value.
Does anyone know how to do this?

```js
function m(r, c) {
  return document.querySelector("table").querySelectorAll("tr")[r].querySelectorAll("td")[c-1].innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div>
<table class="table1" style="width:100%;font-weight:bold ;font-size:13px;text-align:center; border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>3</td>
        </tr>           
</table>
</div>
<a>row 1 : </a><input id="1" ></input><br>
<a>row 2 : </a><input id="2" ></input><br>
<a>row 3 : </a><input id="3" ></input><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind that `m` function to `onchange` event of each `input` selector.

> `onchange` event will be called whenever the input value is changed. (So when the user press `enter` and the value is changed, that event will be called.)

And on `m` function, you can change the values of `td`s based on `event.target.value`.

```js
function m(r, event) {
  const tds = document.querySelector("table").querySelectorAll("tr")[r].querySelectorAll("td");
  tds.forEach((item) => {
    item.innerHTML = event.target.value;
  });
}
```

```html
<div>
<table class="table1" style="width:100%;font-weight:bold ;font-size:13px;text-align:center; border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
             <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>2</td>
             <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>3</td>
             <td>3</td>
        </tr>           
</table>
</div>
<a>row 1 : </a><input id="1" onchange="m(0, event)"></input><br>
<a>row 2 : </a><input id="2" onchange="m(1, event)"></input><br>
<a>row 3 : </a><input id="3" onchange="m(2, event)"></input><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Derek answer is correct but doesn't multiply values, here is the complete function: (I haven't enough reputation to comment Derek answer)

```
<div>
    <table class="table1"
        style="width:100%;font-weight:bold ;font-size:13px;text-align:center; border: 1px solid black;">
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<a>row 1 : </a><input id="1" onchange="m(0, event)"></input><br>
<a>row 2 : </a><input id="2" onchange="m(1, event)"></input><br>
<a>row 3 : </a><input id="3" onchange="m(2, event)"></input><br>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function m(r, event) {
        const tds = document.querySelector("table").querySelectorAll("tr")[r].querySelectorAll("td");
        tds.forEach((item) => {
            item.innerHTML = event.target.value * item.innerHTML;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to monitor changes of the input field. See snippet for an example.

```js
// add a document wide listener for the change event
document.addEventListener("change", multiply);

function multiply(evt) {
  // retrieve the element the event originates from
  const origin = evt.target;
  // continue only if the origin contains [data-row]-value
  // aka event delegation
  if (origin.dataset.row) {
    // continue if origin has value
    if (origin.value > 0) {
      // retrieve the cells from row [dataset.row]
      document.querySelectorAll(`table tr:nth-child(${origin.dataset.row}) td`)
        .forEach(cell => {
          const inputValue = origin.value;
          const cando = inputValue >= +origin.min && inputValue <= +origin.max;
          // continue if value >= 1 and value <= 5 (min, max)
          if (cando && +cell.textContent > 0) {
            // write the product to the cell
            cell.textContent = +cell.textContent * +origin.value;
          }
        });
    }
  }
}
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  width: 40px;
}

.table1 {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <table class="table1">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<p>row 1 : <input data-row="1" id="1" type="number" min="1" max="5" step="1"></p>
<p>row 2 : <input data-row="2" id="2" type="number" min="1" max="5" step="1"></p>
<p>row 3 : <input data-row="3" id="3" type="number" min="1" max="5" step="1"></p>
```